# how to open a new div on button click in php while remaining on same page?

Tags: javascript, html

how to open a new div on button click in php while remaining on same page?

```
<form>
<input type='submit' name='open div' onclick='dont knw what to write here to open a div'/>
</form>
```

Comment: This would be handled by jQuery. If you give more detail on exactly what you want to do, we can help.

Comment: Javascript, there's no need to call external libraries.

Comment: I'm confused by "open a div". What does "open a div" mean.

Comment: What the hell does it have to do with `php`?

Comment: oh people.. i have a form with a button and all i want is that when i click that button new div will open and that div will carry some computations... basically i dont want the computations to be displayed on next page...i want them to be on the very same page... i can do it through function call() in onclick but i need a better solution... i hope i am clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Javascript for this:

```
<button Onclick="javascript_open_new_div();">Create Div</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function javascript_open_new_div() {
        var div = document.createElement("div1");
        document.form_name.appendChild(div1);
    }
    </script>
```

with a framework like jQuery:

```
$("button_selector").click(function() {
      $("form_selector").append("<div></div>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some javascript.

```
<button Onclick="javascript_open_new_div();">Create Div</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function javascript_open_new_div() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.form_name.appendChild(div);
    }
    </script>
```

Also,jQuery is a good helper if you are using then.

```
$("button_selector").click(function() {
          $("form_selector").append("<div></div>")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onClick() {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.id = "newDiv";
    d.textContent = "some text you want to display";
    var f = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(d, f);
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SRBhT/3/

if you want to use ajax for your requests, you should have a look at jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/